# c++ Which is faster, returning a value in a function, or using a reference parameter?

Tags: c++, function, reference

Aside from what's the better or the most secure practice, is it generally faster to return a value in the function, or to just change the parameter by reference? Or is there an even faster method?

Comment: write a test and tell us the answer

Comment: What makes you think one method is faster than the other?

Comment: Even if you test it, the test will be very much depending on the compiler and the target platform.

Comment: The question cannot be answered for all cases.  In some cases, the value is returned in a register which is hard to beat speedwise.  In other cases, the parameter is passed as a pointer and the function dereferences a pointer (maybe 1 extra instruction).  In summary, this is a microoptimization.

Answer (score 2):

A big object with a deep copy will be slow to return by value if RVO doesn't kick in.

But size is not always into play. For example, it will likely be just as fast to return a 1 byte object as it would be to return a 2 or 4, or even 8 byte object, depending on the platform.

Quite often it is not about what is faster, but what is needed in the usage context. In the case of a primitive and when the intent it the output of the value, then it is usually returned by value. When object identity matter or the intent is modification of the actual object, then you return by reference.

There is also the limitation of what is possible. For example, you should never return a function local by reference, because that's a problem waiting to happen. You could return a private member variable by reference, but then again, you could simply have it public instead.

It also depends on what you mean by "return by reference" because that could be C++ style returning by a reference, or C style returning by pointer. The latter is more frequently used, when you dynamically allocate an object in a function and just return a pointer to it, in the case of big or unique objects that is the way to go.

Also, besides RVO there is also move semantics, which still come into play when returning by value. The overhead of deep copies was a long standing issue that was just recently resolved in C++11. Some frameworks like Qt solved the issue earlier by employing shallow copies and using implicitly shared resources.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on both the architecture of the processor and the specific implementation of the compiler.

In general, returning a reference may use one more indirection, so possibly 1-2 more instruction, but that's also a pathway that's so common there is probably some effort spent making it optimal.

So, as mentioned above, you would probably need to measure it.  *However*, tiny changes in the code might change the optimization and so change the results.

As an academic exercise, it might be interesting, but the answer is indeterminate and the result is of little or no practical use.

Comment: Also when doing return by value the compiler can perform copy elision.

Comment: returning by reference- is generally not a good practice (in case of local variables). With rvalue-references and move-ctors (perfect forwarding) returning by value can be fixed completely.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on what kind of value you actually want to return and what your function looks like. E.g. are we talking about abuiltin type, a small/big POD, an array or an object with a very expensive <strike>copy</strike> move constructor?
Especially important is the question if the structure of the function is such, that RVO/NRVO can be applied at all. 
(Named) Return Value Optimization means, that the compiler isn't actually copying the local variable into the return value, but directly constructs the local variable at the memory address that is used for the return value.

It is also important, if the return value is used to initialize a variable at the call site, or to change the value of an already initialized variable. The compiler can usually optimize away the initialization but not necessarily the modification

So, e.g. the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
};
Foo bar(){
    return Foo{ 5 };
}
int main() {
    Foo = bar();
}
```

will result in a single `Foo` object being constructed without any copying being performed.

Aside from potentially eliminating the need to copy anything (not even a pointer - which probably can be usually neglected), using the function return value has another advantage:
The compiler might be better at optimization, because it isn't handed a pointer / reference, so it e.g. doesn't have to worry about aliasing.

So if you return a built-in type, or a small POD, it will definitively be better to use the return value. If, on the other side,  you have to change the values in an array, then it is of course better to use a pointer to that array, instead of returning an array, that is then copied into the target array.

In most other cases: 
***It depends!***

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb : 
if (value is a primitive)
then return by value
else return by reference

If speed not an issue, always return by value, you have less chance to introduce bug that way.